# IOS Animations in For Loop. Adjusted delay for each but still having issues

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I'm creating a pattern matching game. Basically I have 4 square UIViews on a screen with different colors. I want one square to randomly blink followed by another square randomly blinking. For example, when the game starts lets say a red box gets randomly chosen to blink. Now on the second iteration, the red box should blink again followed by another randomly chosen box which lets say it's blue. So now we have red and blue. Now the loop starts again and now it's red, blue, green. This is what i'm trying to accomplish. If this doesn't make sense, please download the IOS game "Mimeo" which should convey exactly what i'm trying to do. Could someone please help me? I'm not having any luck and i've tried seeking out help elsewhere with no luck.

```
//  Created by Gary Dorman on 9/26/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Gary Dorman. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var enemyArray = [Int]()
var userArray = [Int]()
var currentScore = 0
var highScore = 0
var randomNumber = 0

@IBOutlet weak var RedBox: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var GreenBox: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var BlueBox: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var YellowBox: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var ScoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var TitleImageView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func startGameButton(sender: UIButton) {
    self.resetCurrentScoreAndLabel()
    self.increaseLevel()
}

func increaseLevel(){
    var delayTime = 1.0
    randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(4) + 1)
    enemyArray.append(randomNumber)
    for level in 1...enemyArray.count{
       animateColorBox(self.enemyArray[level - 1], delay: delayTime)
        delayTime++
        print(enemyArray[level - 1])
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureBorderOnColorBoxes()
}

func configureBorderOnColorBoxes(){

    RedBox.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    GreenBox.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    BlueBox.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    YellowBox.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

    RedBox.layer.borderWidth = 3
    GreenBox.layer.borderWidth = 3
    BlueBox.layer.borderWidth = 3
    YellowBox.layer.borderWidth = 3
}

func resetCurrentScoreAndLabel(){
    currentScore = 0
    ScoreLabel.text = "Score: \(currentScore)"
}

func animateColorBox(tagNumber: Int, delay: Double){
    let pauseBetweenAnimation = 1.25
    let originalColor:UIColor = self.view.viewWithTag(tagNumber)!.backgroundColor!
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: (delay - 1) * pauseBetweenAnimation, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.view.viewWithTag(tagNumber)!.alpha = 0.25   
        }, completion: { finished in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: (delay - 1) * pauseBetweenAnimation, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
                 self.view.viewWithTag(tagNumber)!.alpha = 1

        }, completion: nil)
    })
}
}
```

Comment: In `animateColorBox` you do not want any delay in the second call to `animateWithDuration`.

Comment: I actually was able to get it to work. The code below worked.

Comment: Then you should accept that answer to indicate that it answered your question.

Comment: I did. Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: You should go back to your other questions and do the same if any of the answers actually solved your issue.

Comment: Okay thanks! Will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that might work for you:

```
func increaseLevel(){
// Set the delay time
var delayTime = 1.0 // This isn't actually used here

// Find a new random number
randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(4) + 1)

// Append new random number to chained array
enemyArray.append(randomNumber)

// Call the animation method
animateColorBox(counter: 0)
}




func animateColorBox( counter counter: Int){

// If the tag number is within the enemyArray bounds
if( counter < enemyArray.count ){
    tagNumber = enemyArray[counter];

    // Set pause coefficient
    let pauseBetweenAnimation = 1.25

    // Save the original color for this view
    let originalColor:UIColor = self.view.viewWithTag(tagNumber)!.backgroundColor!

    // Do an animation for this view
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations:
        {
            self.view.viewWithTag(tagNumber)!.alpha = 0.25
        }, completion:
            { finished in

            // If finished with previous animation
            if( finished ){

                // Then set alpha back to normal
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
                        self.view.viewWithTag(tagNumber)!.alpha = 1

                    }, completion:
                {
                    finished in

                    // If the view has its alpha back to normal
                    if( finished ){

                        // Call animateColorBox on next view in array
                        animateColorBox( counter: counter + 1);
                    }

                })// End UIView animation
            }// end if finished

    })// end UIView Animation
}// end if counter < enemyArray.count
}
```

With this approach, if I am thinking about this correctly from what I think you want, you are able to finish the execution of the dimming and undimming of a given UIView in the set before you start the animation for the next view. Let me know if this works for you.

Edit:

I realize I took out the pause between animations, but you can put that in yourself in the delay area to tune it to your needs.

Oh and I realize my first post doesn't do a check for the value in the enemy array, so let me change something.

Comment: // Call animateColorBox on next view in array
                        animateColorBox(self.enemyArray[counter+1], counter + 1); I am getting array index out of range here.

Comment: @GaryDorman Yeah I fixed the code because I realized that error would pop up, check it again.

Comment: Still not working for that same line. Missing 1st parameter.

Comment: @GaryDorman Did you update the animateColorBox definition? Because now it's only one input. And make sure you don't forget to add the line right under the first if statement where tagNumber is set.

Comment: Wow it works. I don't understand the logic yet but thank you so much!

Comment: @GaryDorman No problem! Glad it works! Feel free to ask me questions about it if you don't totally get what I did.

Comment: func animateColorBox(counter counter: Int)     This kind of confuses me in regards to the counter counter part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90734/discussion-between-choward-and-gary-dorman).